# (How) Can you implement snail HTTP (comet/long lived connections) in Flash?

Tags: flash, streaming, comet

I am very interested in streaming data for web-applications. I have tried out some javascript libraries, but the hacks and browser-incompatibilities drive me crazy ! HTML5 will hopefully standardize streaming data, but until then, hopefully I can resort to Flash to make this work in all browsers. Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with all the functionality that Flash offers.

I have tried loadVariables.onData in Flash 8, but it doesn't support streaming data. The data is only available after the request has been finished. Is there any way to call a function every time new data is returned ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I'm not familiar with what you're doing, it sounds like you should be looking at [URLStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/index.html). When you're loading things that Flash intuitively understands (MP3s, JPGs, SWFs and so on) then you would normally use a [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/Loader.html), and then too you can get [progress events](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#event:progress), but I'm guessing you're talking about loading arbitrary data into a ByteArray, and URLStream should give you all the low-level access you need.

That's assuming you're using AS3, and Flash Player 9+. I wouldn't swear to it, but I'm pretty sure what you're looking for is not possible under AS2.

Comment: Thanks, URLStream seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to stream a single file, use URLStream, as fenomas suggested. If you want an open connection that can both send and receive data, the class you're looking for is [XMLSocket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/net/XMLSocket.html). Should work on anything past Flash 5.

Answer (score 0):

As Moss Collum and fenomas have suggested, there's `URLStream` and `XMLSocket`. But if you want to interact with a server on a binary level, you can read and write bytes with a `Socket` object.

Bear in mind that any network communication is subject to Flash Player's very rigid Security Model. You may find that learning about this will be time very well spent.